# Can I teach English at a community college with only a Bachelor's degree?

Tags: job-search, education, community-college

Can I teach at a community college with only a Bachelor's degree?

I am interested in the liberal arts. Specifically: English.

I read someone else's post with a similar question, and the responses really shot it down. That is, of course, teaching with only a Bachelor's. But I found on another site: Higher Ed Jobs, many community colleges require only a Bachelor's. Do they want the candidate to be a PHd student or something?

Comment: If you're trying to better understand the requirements of these job listings you mentioned, please quote the relevant parts and link to the listing. Without those details, this is a duplicate of the other post.

Comment: _many community colleges require only a Bachelor's_ Teaching English or Teaching English as a second language (ESL)? You need to read the job ads carefully.

Comment: FYI, in the U.S.A. during the 1990s when I was involved in several job searches, the nearly universal requirement for community college teaching was a Masters degree (or higher) and at least 18 semester hours of graduate credit in the field you intend to teach. Thus, someone with an M.A. degree in math and who also has 18 semester hours of graduate credit in English would be qualified to teach math or English.

Comment: Thank You, And to ff524 - should I dig out some job descriptions?? Again, thank you to everyone who responded

Comment: @ff524♦   Hello, ff524  I am this gentleman who asked the question about teaching at a community college with a BA. You responded. I am trying to get back to you. Now I am not playing around. Because I have been threatened to be blocked from the site. Can you help me any further?? You mention a "link to the listing". If I provided this could you help me further. I found a site 'Higher Ed Jobs'.  Again, I am asking in a nice way. And would certainly appreciate any help. Hope to hear from you to work all this out. Thank You so much!!!!

Comment: Use the [edit] link to update your post if you have additional information that makes it distinct from the duplicate.

Comment: @ff524 How would this help me? Can Stack Exchange or anyone at SE help me?? If I put job info from this site I mentioned, could someone help me? Is this site just for technical fields?? I am interested in the Liberal arts!! Thanks again

Comment: ff524♦So are you suggesting I put a job listing in the post, and say for example, ask everyone on SE -- if I should bother to apply for the job. I guess that is essentially what I am asking, and what I gleaned from your post. Thanks again!!!

Comment: @ff524♦ So are you suggesting I put a job listing in the post, and say for example, ask everyone on SE -- if I should bother to apply for the job. I guess that is essentially what I am asking, and what I gleaned from your post. Thanks Again!!!

Comment: @Ben Crowell Can you help me? Do you understand what ff524 wants me to do?? Create a new question, and put a job listing in it?? Then what can Stack Exchange do for me?? Can you answer if SE is right for me?? if not I will go away!!